# LINQ Dictionary of Dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I'm to create a dictionary of dictionaries of in LINQ matched on a parent id.

I have a data model

```
 Pseudo-Model:
    Int ID;
    Int Namel
    Int? ParentID;
```

I want to create a Dictionary Of Dictonaries. 
The first Dictionary is the ID of those whose are only a parent
and the dictionary with-in it would contain the ID, Name.

I know I could do this through a looping but I want to figure out how to do it though LINQ.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this?  Wouldn't it be easier to create a flat dictionary of <Id, ObjectComposedOfIdAndName>?

Comment: I want to maintain the parent Child Relationship, ie tree, I want to see all of the leaves

Comment: Interesting...
Give it a shot yourself and explain the issues that you're having with example code.  Until then, this isn't a valid question.

Comment: Hint:  Look up `GroupBy` and `ToDictionary`

Comment: The problem I'm having is understand what to write for the LINQ. 

var Territory = _model.Terrtories.groupby( t => t.ParentID).ToDictionary(???\)

Comment: @user1938988 You're on the right track.  Look as the docs and examples for `ToDictionary` - the first parameter is the key selector and the second is the value selector.  Hint 2:  The value selector is going to call `ToDictionary` _again_.

Comment: Once I do a group by what is the object I'm acting on? Isn't it an IQueryable of Territories?  

This is what I would think to do based off of what you said but it wont compile

var temp = _model.TerritoryRightsLookups.GroupBy(i => i.FK_ParentID).ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Value.ToDictionary(t.ID, t.Name));

Comment: It's a grouping with a `Key` value that you can iterate over.  I've added a solution since you've gotten part way there.

Comment: Also add your current attempts to your question so they can be formatted properly.

Comment: Whats current attempts?

Comment: The code you put in your comments (even if it's incomplete).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`GroupBy` creates an `IGrouping` with a `Key` value that you can iterate over (or make additional LINQ calls on).

`ToDictionary` takes two selectors - one for the key and one for the value.  The key for the outer dictionary is `ParentID` and the value is *another* dictionary, whose key is `ID` and value is `Name`.

Assuming that `ID` is unique (at least within a `ParentID` group) you can do:

```
 _model.Terrtories
       .GroupBy(i => i.ParentID.HasValue ? i.ParentID.Value : 0)   
       .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,   // outer dictionary key
                     g => g.ToDictionary(i => i.ID,   // inner dictionary key
                                         i => i.Name));  // inner dictionary value
```

Note that the second parameter to the outer `ToDictionary` is translating the items within each group into an inner dictionary.

Comment: This Kinda Makes sense Now, I'm just confused on how what its acting on after the group by because now its a group of something.

Also Is there a way to do the group by and if the parent ID is null assign it to 0?

Comment: it's a grouping of `Territory` objects.  `IGrouping` implements `IEnumerable<T>` so you can use Linq on it as if it were a separate collection.

Comment: I couldn't grasp that I was acting on a IEnumberable after grouping.  This works now Also to Fix the Null issue I precase all null to 0

var Terr = _model.TerritoryRightsLookups.ToList();
                    Terr.ForEach(i => { 
                        i.FK_ParentID = (i.FK_ParentID == null) ? 0 : i.FK_ParentID;
                    });


var temp = Terr.GroupBy(i => i.FK_ParentID).ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.ToDictionary(g => g.ID, g => g.Name));

Comment: @DStanely Thanks for the help on this, I still refer to this question when storing my tree structures sometimes

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you would do with this, but here's what it could look like.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int,string>>()
{
    { 1, new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            {1, "Name1"},
            {2, "Name2"},
            {3, "Name3"},
        }
    },
    { 2, new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            {1, "Something1"},
            {2, "Something2"},
            {3, "Something3"},
        }
    },
};
```

If you want to represent a parent / child relationship, why not create a parent / child relationship?

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I know how to code this, I just want to do it in LINQ so I do not have to write out all of the code and I know how to do it for future reference